# MongoDB collection count returns -1

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection which returns -1 when I call `db.collection.count()`, however if I call `db.collection.find()` then one document is returned.

Does the negative count suggest something is wrong with the collection? I can't find anything within the documentation.

I attempted inserting a dummy document into the collection - which changed the count to 2. After removing this document the count is now at the correct value of 1 with just the original document stored.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt database. Have you tried to run repair/repairDatabase() ?

Comment: @Jaco is there a way to confirm that the database is corrupt? The documentation recommends doing resyncs if using a replicaset, but obviously I would need to confirm that other replicas are healthy. Or any way to debug the cause? This has now been seen with two instances of the same application.

Comment: You could run `db.collection.validate({full:true})` if the issue occurs again

Comment: @Jaco I'm actually seeing a very similar error with a different node in the same replicaset - It was returning a count of 0 (despite one document being present), after running the validate command it now returns the correct value of 1. (the validation also returned no errors)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that I missed this section of the documentation:

> After an unclean shutdown of a mongod using the Wired Tiger storage
>   engine, count statistics reported by count() may be inaccurate.
>
> The amount of drift depends on the number of insert, update, or delete
>   operations performed between the last checkpoint and the unclean
>   shutdown. Checkpoints usually occur every 60 seconds. However, mongod
>   instances running with non-default --syncdelay settings may have more
>   or less frequent checkpoints.
>
> Run validate on each collection on the mongod to to restore the
>   correct statistics after an unclean shutdown.

Running `db.unboundCollection.validate({full:true})` resolved the issue.